# How do I break down a key value pair into a JSON string in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Given a key value pair such as "a.b.c.d" = "e", how can I get the following JSON string:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "d": "e"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question and post what have you tried and the issues you are facing. Note that SO it is not a code writing service. Please take some time and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct a dictionary hierarchy and then convert that to a JSON string.

Given a

- key consisting of a dot (`.`) separated list of path elements
- and a value,

you can build your dictionary object as follows:

```swift
var jsonObject: [String: Any]

var path = key.split(separator: ".").map { String($0) }
let lastKey = path.popLast()!
jsonObject = [lastKey: value]

for element in path.reversed() {
    jsonObject = [element: jsonObject]
}
```

Then you can can get a pretty printed version (as in your example above) as follows:

```swift
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [.prettyPrinted])
let encoded = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
```

To get a compact (non-pretty) version, omit the `.prettyPrinted` option (but leave the array brackets).

```swift
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [])
let encoded = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
```

Here's the whole thing packaged into a function:

```swift
func jsonFromKeyValue(key: String, value: String) -> String {
    var jsonObject: [String: Any]

    var path = key.split(separator: ".").map { String($0) }
    let lastKey = path.popLast()!
    jsonObject = [lastKey: value]

    for element in path.reversed() {
        jsonObject = [element: jsonObject]
    }

    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [.prettyPrinted])
    let encoded = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!

    return encoded
}
```

Try it with:

```swift
let jsonObject = jsonFromKeyValue(key: "a.b.c.d", value: "e")
print(jsonObject)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much cleaner than the recursive solution I came up with.